# JavaScript Comparison Operators Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

i need compare two values using Less Than or Greater Than, but it's not working fine. Here below my code.

```
//JAVASCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
function validform()
{
    var balanvar = document.myform.balance.value,
        currntvar = document.myform.currnt.value;     
    if( currntvar == "" ) { document.myform.currnt.focus(); document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "red"; return false; } // Must be filled error
    if(currntvar > balanvar) { document.myform.currnt.focus(); document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "red"; return false; } else { document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "green"; } // Maximum value error
}
</script>
//HTML
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="balance" id="balanceid" value="12000"/>
<input type="text" name="currnt" id="curntid"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed" onclick="return validform();"/>
</form>
```

What i want is, i have to enter less than "balance" value in "currnt" text box, if i entered maximum value compare to "balance" text box mean, have to throw error message.

Problem Is, when clicking proceed without filling "currnt" it's showing error. and when entering value 15000 in "currnt" means its showing error. But when entering value 100000 in "currnt" means its not giving error. i don't know what error is this. please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Javascript math text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395777/basic-javascript-math-text-field). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604138/how-to-get-an-input-value-dynamically-and-perform-arithmetic-operations-using-ja, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258696/instantiate-a-variable-out-of-text-field-value-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614374/plus-arithmetic-operation, etc. etc.

Comment: Asked and answered multiple times. But actually you don't even need to come to SO for this. Finding the answer to this problem yourself would not be much harder than simply stopping the debugger at the line in question, observing `document.myform.balance.value`, and noting that it was a string.

Comment: @torazaburo see i know basics of js only, i tried but could not identify error. that's why i asked here.

Comment: How did you try? SO is not a crowd-sourced site for spotting bugs that the poster cannot find because he or she does not know how to use basic development tools. Do you understand how to use devtools? For instance, do you know how to set a breakpoint? If not, stop everything you are doing right now and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.value` property returns a string. hence you comparisons are done using string comparisons, which most of the time do yield other results than number comparisons.

To solve that, convert to numbers first using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
function validform()
{
    var balanvar = parseFloat( document.myform.balance.value ),
        currntvar = parseFloat( document.myform.currnt.value );     
    if( isNaN( currntvar ) ) { document.myform.currnt.focus(); document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "red"; return false; } // Must be filled error
    if(currntvar > balanvar) { document.myform.currnt.focus(); document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "red"; return false; } else { document.getElementById("curntid").style.borderColor = "green"; } // Maximum value error
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this code totally not working, is anything there to add extra? i mean jquery library?

Comment: `currntvar == ""` here makes me uncomfortable. It gives the illusion that leaving `currnt.value` empty would make this fire, which it wouldn't as `parseFloat("") === NaN` which `!= ""`

Comment: @RGraham My mistake - didn't read the code concentrated enough. Fixed that.

Comment: @RGraham sorry i could not understand what you saying exactly, if you don't mind can you provide a corrected code.

Comment: @Piruthvi Fixed the code. If it is still not working, please describe "not working" a little more.

Comment: @Piruthvi The code has been "fixed". Not that it was *wrong* as such, just didn't describe what it did as well as it does now.

Comment: Rather than answering this question for the n'th time, it would be a better use of everyone's time if you provided guidance to the OP on how he could track down such errors himself, since he seems not to have completely mastered such debugging skills.